# Can I use 2 different models of Netgear Powerline Network Adapters together?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, powerline-networking

I have a set of **XETB1001** and a set of **XAVB101**, I want to use the set of **XAVB101** because they are 200mbps and 1 **XETB1001**, is that possible, or do I need to keep them paired?

Links to Products from Newegg.com

XETB1001 - newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122318

XAVB101 - newegg.com/product/product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided they both implement the same Homeplug standard, then yes.

Comment: How could I find that out?

Comment: Google. I had a quick look at it seems they are "HomePlug Compatible". I think HomePlug has two standards though.