# Connect HomePlug AV Powerline home equipment from different vendors to the same network

Tags: home-networking, powerline-networking

I've been reading a bit about the Powerline specifications, and I got the impression that all the equipment that has the HomePlug AV certificate should interact with similar equipment from another vendor.

I'm trying to make it work, but I'm having some problems. I'm using 2 Lindy PowerLine adapters (that, naturally, can connect to each other), and I have another couple of adapters, from SMC. If I connect one of the SMC to the mains, it won't connect to the other 2 (e.g. the SMC is isolated from the rest of the network).

I've tried the "config utility" that is provided by different vendors (Power Packet utiliy), but it's very limited and I can't do much with it.

Shouldn't all this be "plug and play"? Or is it all just "marketing talk", and the equipments won't talk to each other? Does anyone have a setup like this (HomePlug AV equipment from different vendors, together on the same PowerLine network)?

Thank you for your attention.

Cheers!

Comment: Related: [Can I use 2 different models of Netgear Powerline Network Adapters together?] (http://superuser.com/questions/138586)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and eventually found the answer by phoning Solwise about 5 times - you will need the Homeplug software - either from the disc with your plugs or downloaded from Solwise. Yes I know it doesn't work but all will become clear :-).

I think your problem is the network names are different on the two plugs or sets of plugs.

The software will set the network name to HomePlugAV or similar by plugging them in to your PC or laptop one at a time. My software didn't pick the plugs up at all but there are several possible reasons why. The big answer for me was FIREWALL turn off or disable windows firewall and any antivirus software and the Homeplug software should pick up the homeplugs - one at a time set the network name by using the security tab and "setting local" button.

Another possibility if using a laptop is the wireless connection is getting used instead of the wired connection so if problems still occur disable wireless card in device manager.

Remember to enable all devices, firewalls and antivirus software after successfully renaming the networks on all the plugs - they will all recognise each other then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have to try it, I wasn't aware that you could change the network name for the devices :) I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Changing the Network names is not correct, it's the Network Management key that has to be changed.